# SharingRule is not being shown as RowCause in OpportunityShare record

Tags: apex, opportunity, sharing-rule, apex-sharing

I have granted a User access to an Opportunity record through an Opportunity sharing rule. Now I can see in the **UserRecordAccess** Object that the User has access to this particular Opportunity record. But when I search in the  **OpportunityShare** object, the record is not being shown.

As per the article on OpportunityShare , a record should be created with RowCause value as '**Rule**' (User or group has access via an opportunity sharing rule).

Comment: what is an OWD  and which access do you grant with sharing rule?

Comment: OWD is private and only Read Access via Sharing rule

Comment: are you granting access to the user, that is not an owner of a record?

Comment: Yes. The user is not the Owner/Team Member or above the Owner's Role Hierarchy

Comment: He may have access to opportunity due to access to the related Account record